# USA visa denied. Can we reapply in a month?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, proof-of-ties

My girlfriend's visa was refused today. Mine has been approved. We want to go on holiday to the USA. I have a good job and income and I will guarantee her and also pay for her trip as indicated on the visa form. We want to submit a new application within 1 month. Is it advisable?

She is participating in education at an accredited institute, has no income, nor has children but a mother and brother, father has already died. We did not include any documents of the training she is following, but that was indicated in the form. I need advice, now I want to submit a form with appendices for the study program. Is it advisable to include an employer's statement with a minimum income?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general advice we have is that unless there was a **serious error in the reading of your file** you should not apply again. Not having minor documents included in your portfolio (that may be referred to by other documents) is not a serious error or omission.

You don’t give the specific reason code your visa was denied but it was most probably the generic “not enough ties to the home country” reason. This is very hard to argue against.

If you applied again in such a short span of time with nothing changing in your material circumstances, you’d not only likely get denied again but you’d get labeled as a serial applicant with negative remarks on your file.

Accept that there isn’t much you can do this time and go on vacation instead to the EU, Canada, or Australia or somewhere else where the burden isn’t quite so high right now.